# Error with Dynamic Row level security in Multidimensional OLAP

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, row-level-security, multidimensional-cube

I tried to run a Multidimensional project with Dynamic RLS.
I used a [Sample](http://bharathonsqlserver.blogspot.com/2016/07/dynamic-security-in-ssas-in-detail.html) for implement it.

In my sample scenario, I've a cub like below :

[image]

I tried to write correct MDX query for test result of users permission.

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Point Transaction Count],[Measures].[Amount],[Measures].[Balance]} ON 0,
NonEmpty ([Club].[Club].[Club].MEMBERS,([Users].[User Name].&[[MyDomain]\a.ghasemi],[Measures].[User Permission Count])) ON 1
FROM [DynamicPointTransaction]
GO
```

|  | Point Transaction Count | Amount | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TestClub | 30 | 34151 | 99210 |

This result is true and when I change user name worked well in SSMS query editor.

Now, my problem in Dynamic RLS, When I tried set query for use dynamically users in VS browser I catch a error for permission dimension.

> The 'Club' attribute in the 'Club' dimension has a generated dimension security expression that is not valid.

I created a Role by DimesionData with Allowed member set like below :

```
NonEmpty (
[Club].[Club Id].[Club Id].Members,
(
StrToMember ("[Users].[User Name].&[" + UserName () + "]"),
[Measures].[User Permission Count]
)
)
```

Add membership, add read permission for cub and dimensions.

When browse with Role or users raise this error :

[image: Choice user]

[image: Error]

No different between Role and Users... error is stable.
When choice Admin users, I don't have any error.